# Deno launch from VSCode with rebuild

Tags: visual-studio-code, launch, deno

I am able to run deno from command line ([deno vs ts-node : what's the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428120/deno-vs-ts-node-whats-the-difference)). I would like to run it from VS code. I also tried to compile it first (by deno run) and run from vs code on result.
I made [repo](https://github.com/senpl/vscode_deno_example) to show how to run it, but it runs two times, first time to compile source, second to run in vscode on compiled source. I would like to just run deno from vs code directly or compile ts file with deno before run them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile TS files first without running the code, you could try `deno fetch <filename>`. This command downloads all the remote dependencies, compiling the code, but not evaluating the code.

Not clear what does "run deno from VSCode directly" mean, but you might visit [vscode-deno](https://github.com/justjavac/vscode-deno) and file a feature request.

Comment: Looks like fetch do more then fetch the dependencies. Anyway it compile as well. Thanks